# Streaming Videos from Azure ( Blob or Media Services)

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, media, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have an MVC 4 website hosted in azure that needs  to upload a video and on a different page allow that uploaded video to be streamed back to a client player.

The first option allows the user to upload and encode the video (.mp4)
The second option is I manually upload and encode the video and provide the url to the user.

In either case, the video would be presented to the users on another page.

Im having a devil of a time trying to get this to work.  Any suggestions/working samples?

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code for my c# application and it works properly.

```
public static string getBlobStreamURL(string fsBloblFilePath, string fsdirectory)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(fsdirectory);
            var cloudBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fsBloblFilePath);
            var SharedAccessSignature = cloudBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            });
            var StreamURL = string.Format("{0}{1}", cloudBlob.Uri, lsSharedAccessSignature);
            return StreamURL;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165110/how-can-i-host-and-embed-a-video-in-an-mvc-application-on-azure/14167807#14167807) on how to serve video's from Azure.

You'll want to use Azure Blob Storage to store the files. This will scale very well, let you take advantage of the Azure CDN for faster delivery, and the outgoing traffic won't count against your website instances.

You can then use any HTML5 or flash player you want. One important thing, make sure when saving the file, you set the Content Type. You can also change the [Azure Service Version](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2012/streaming-video-from-azure-blob-storage/) to support video seek.