# What is the best way of hosting a video on Azure?

Tags: azure, video-streaming

To clarify: I have a website hosted in Azure. I want to add a 1.5 minute howto video. I can't imagine it will get shown more than a few tens or hundreds a month (maybe a few thousand if the site takes off).

I was planning on using [Azure Media Player](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/azure-media-player-full-setup) to play the video.

In relation to this I thought the video would sit in a [streaming endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-vod-get-started).

But this seems an expensive way of doing this. Are there better ways (especially cheaper)?

EDIT: is it possible to host the video elsewhere and have it embedded in Azure?

Comment: It's vital to know that Azure Media Services and Azure Media Player are being retired in 2024. Microsoft encourage developers to use 3rd party services now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/azure-media-services-retirement

Answer (score 4):

The cheap way to do this would be to place the video in a blob storage then play it using a web page.

There is a video explaining how to do this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmzns7PgP0A

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended to use Media Service:  video-on-demand, content delivery service with an [Azure Media Services application in the Azure portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-vod-get-started)

Azure Media Services lets you deliver any media, on virtually any device, to anywhere in the world using the cloud. The collection of services provide encoding, live or on-demand streaming, content protection and indexing for video and audio content.

The Windows Azure Media Services platform has four types of services: content uploading, encoding, encrypting content and streaming.

Media Service Pricing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/media-services/

Additional information : [Streaming Videos from Azure ( Blob or Media Services)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369093/streaming-videos-from-azure-blob-or-media-services)

Comment: Thanks that is what I am doing. Just wondered if there are alternatives.

Comment: Upload it to blob storage and use AMP to stream, Media service is used to stream multibit rate but if it's just a single video to show the above approach would be the best, You can also Upload it to storage and use endpoint in AMP

Comment: It's vital to know that Azure Media Services and Azure Media Player are being retired in 2024. Microsoft encourage developers to use 3rd party services now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/azure-media-services-retirement

Comment: @JamesMcCormack, this comment should be "pinned" to the top of this question.